# Knockout observable element does not updated in IE properly

Tags: internet-explorer, data-binding, knockout.js, observable

I have this really simple observable element which for some reason does not update in IE8

```
<body>
<form data-bind="submit: show">
<input type="text" data-bind="value: someText" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var ViewModel = function () {
        var self = this;
        self.someText = ko.observable('initial value');

        self.show = function () {
            alert(self.someText());
            self.someText('');
        }
    }

    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
</script>
</body>
```

So, when enter is clicked, the value inputed into textbox should be displayed. Everything fine in mozilla, opera, chrome. IE does not see any changes and always alerts with a empty string. Why? 
[Here you can run this piece of code](http://jsfiddle.net/GCbw2/)

Comment: I don't fully understand the behavioral differences for IE compared to other browsers but it appears the change events are not triggered _before_ the submit event is fired. Knockout relies on those events to keep the view model up to date. You may have to adjust your code to work around that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorry, I should google it carefully. The problem was in different event after which observable element should be updated. Little fix for IE looks like this

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: someText, valueUpdate: 'keydown'" />
```

Comment: I was almost frantic. Worked somewhereelse  as I was using code above. Could figure out why it wasn't here even after stepping through the code...